# How do I enforce the order which error messages are displayed when using validation annotations?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I have the below model, view and error messages.

**Model**

```
public class LoginModel {
    @Required(message = "validation.required.email")
    public String email;

    @Required(message = "validation.required.password")
    public String password;
}
```

**View**

```
@for((field, validationErrors) <- myForm.errors) {
    @for(validationError <- validationErrors) {
        <li>@Messages(validationError.message)</li>
    }
}
```

**conf/messages**

```
error.no_email=You must enter an email
error.no_password=You must enter a password
```

The message "You must enter a password" appears before the "You must enter an email". I would like them in the same order I have them on my form (which is email followed by password). Is there a way to define the order which error messages are displayed when errors are added automatically by play from validation annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of an overheard (and I don't like the solution) but it's possible via:

```
@for(error <- form("email").errors) {
    <li>@Messages(error.message)</li>
}

@for(error <- form("password").errors) {
    <li>@Messages(error.message)</li>
}
```

It still means that the order of the messages are not guaranteed for each field, but at least you can enforce the order at a field level so they can match up to the order of the fields on your form.

Answer (score 2):

Play Form internally uses `HashMap` for storing validation errors, thus order is not enforced. You can grab the sources from [github](https://github.com/playframework/playframework), extend the form and replace `HashMap` occurrences with `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Really should've looked at the source first, myself... thanks.

Comment: It could be a valid pull request. Go and contribute! :-)

Comment: Found a solution, see my answer. It's not the best but does what I need it to. +1 for help :)

Comment: At least much easier than extending Form.

Answer (score 0):

In **play 2.6.0** the method [allErrors()](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.x/framework/src/play-java-forms/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L696) has been introduced. It returns an unmodifiableList of all errors.

This allows one to ...

**1.** ... implement `public List<ValidationError> validate()` at the model class [like described here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaForms#Advanced-validation)

**2.** ... retrieve the ordered list later in the controller when testing if `form.hasErrors()`.

This wasn't possible in versions before play 2.6, because the errors were [stored in a map](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L125). Since play 2.6 form errors are [stored in a list](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.x/framework/src/play-java-forms/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L87) and [errors()](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.x/framework/src/play-java-forms/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L704) has been marked as deprecated.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question on how to order the error messages.

Comment: You define the ordering in your implementation of validate() at the model. In play 2.5 it wasn't possible to preserve the ordering because of the internal datastructure of Form.errors. Since play 2.6 it is possible to retrieve errors in the same order as they were added by validate. Answer edited. Also corrected link to `allErrors()` implementation by referencing the exact version.

Comment: Hi @DavidSpence I corrected the links to the sources by referencing the correct branches. This should make it much clearer. I had the exact same problem as described in your question. Updating to play 2.6 worked for me.